# Databases for things like dictionaries, zip codes etc

Tags: mysql, database, open-source

Where can I find/get databases for things like dictionaries, list of states, zip codes, cities etc? Preferably open-source or free and for MySQL but converting from another db or XML to MySQL with PHP would be a fun side project.

Comment: You probably search for database layouts of the things you mentioned? Did you look at open-source projects in those areas? You might find such things there.

Comment: Im having trouble with searching and don't know where to look. I'm looking for more than local area stuff. A lot sites have list of states, and cities in the states for USA so I figured there's probably a database somewhere for that. Same goes for dictionaries and whatever else that might be useful to future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often used the data of http://www.geonames.org/ 
There's a nice tutorial at the forum to learn how to import the date into a MySQL-Database:
http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/732.page

They have a webservice, too: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

If the datasets are not sufficient enough, there are a lot of open APIs:

http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=zip%20codes

Answer (score 2):

There are many places to find interesting data online: 
The [world bank](http://data.worldbank.org/) has released an extensive set of data you can download and use for free. You can also extract some of the structured data from wikipedia through the service [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About). If you want to use more specific data from either corporate or governmental institutions (how much did your government spend last year? Where does the crimes find place?) check out Open Knowledge Foundations data repository at [The Data Hub](http://thedatahub.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/).

Also available via Amazon EC2 "Public Datasets" feature.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I love http://snipplr.com for this. Just do a search for `mysql countries` (replace countries with whatever full mysql formatted db you want) and there's an excellent chance you'll find what you're looking for.

I couldn't find a dictionary on there though, so I'd recommend doing an XML to SQL conversion of http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/ 's db.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of good stuff at http://www.data.gov/, though most of it would probably have to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most accurate way to get such info is by extracting it from http://www.openstreetmap.org/